# Create sparse pandas dataframe from dict with zeroes, without creating dense version first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I'm working with very sparse data, and I want to create sparse data frame with zeroes as missing values, without
ever creating a dense data frame.

This is some example input:

```py
record = {
            0: {
                "item1": 1,
                "item2": 3
            },
            1: {"item1": 2,
                "item3": 1,
                "item4": 50},
        }
```

I can create the correct dataframe like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
dfs = (
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
            record, orient="index", dtype=pd.SparseDtype("int", np.nan)
        )
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(pd.SparseDtype("int", 0))
    )
```

Giving the correct output

```py
   item1  item2  item3  item4
0      1      3      0      0
1      2      0      1     50
# dfs.sparse.density => 0.625
```

However, the `fillna(0)` call created a dense matrix which was then converted to a sparse matrix again.

I want the dataframe to be of type `SparseDtype("int", 0)` straight away instead.
I would like to do:

```py
dfs2 = (
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
            record, orient="index", dtype=pd.SparseDtype("int", 0)
        )
    )
```

But this does not work.

```py
dfs2
   item1  item2  item3  item4
0      1    3.0    NaN    NaN
1      2    NaN    1.0   50.0
dfs2.sparse.density => crash: Can only use the .sparse accessor with Sparse data.
```

I understand why it doesn't work - it doesn't know to make the nan values into zeroes.
How can I make it understand that without ever creating a dense data frame?

Comment: Before you move on with dataframe, did you consider using numpy to create a sparse matrix, only then convert it into the dataframe?

Comment: I tried to use csr_matrix from scipy, but couldn't get it to work. The issue is that most of these don't fill in missing values properly.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't try it jet.

But did you try something like:

```
def fillVoid(x):
    return 0 if x == '' else x


df = df.apply(fillVoid)
```

But it should take care of your Nans without doing to mutch shenanigans in the backend

Comment: This gives
AssertionError: Non array-like type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> must have the same length as the index

Logically, isn't the result of this that the df is no longer sparse? All nans are replaced by zeroes, but the dtype is still `Sparse[int, nan]`?